# Performance of RSA based on keysize

Tags: cryptography, performance, rsa

A theoretical question not depending on implementation, how much of a decrease in performance is 1024bit vs 4096bit RSA?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [RSA key lengths](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_key_length.shtml):

> [...]
>
> With every doubling of the RSA key length, **decryption is 6-7 times times slower.**
>
> Figure 1 shows how decryption time
>   increases with modulus length. The
>   timings were made on a 2GHz Pentium.
>
> [image]
>
> The key length also affects the speed
>   of *encryption*, but it's usually the
>   speed of *decryption* that we're more
>   concerned about because (a) that's the
>   part that takes place on the server,
>   and (b) decryption is much much slower
>   than encryption, because the
>   decryption exponent is huge (whereas
>   the encryption exponent is typically
>   small).
>
> If we use a 4096-bit modulus, it takes
>   around a second of CPU time to decrypt
>   a block of data. Even if you were able
>   to sacrifice this amount of CPU to
>   every log on, it leaves us with the
>   problem that an attacker can
>   effectively burn a second of CPU time
>   on our server by firing some random
>   data at it. With a 1024-bit key
>   length, decryption takes just 25
>   milliseconds; with suitable
>   restrictions on the rate of login
>   attemps (and thus decryptions) we
>   allow per remote client, protecting
>   against a "CPU burn" attack is more
>   feasible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pascal, I searched but couldn't find this info.

Comment: Just a note: Bear in mind that this advice does not necessarily hold for other ciphers - particularly symmetric ones!