# Node-RSA decryption very slow in React Native

Tags: react-native, encryption-asymmetric, node-rsa

I tried to decrypt a string encrypted with a publicKey on the server using Node-RSA in my React Native app with the privateKey using the same Node-RSA lib, it takes about 2-3 secs to decrypt a simple object containing only userId and iat.

```
const privKey = new NodeRSA(dKey);
let base64 = privKey.decrypt(payload, 'utf8');
return jwt_decode(base64);
```

the second instruction usual takes too long to execute, what could I be missing out.

Comment: What's the bit length of the key you are using? 
Try using a 512 or 1024 bit key for quicker decryption.

Comment: @NitishAnand - Probably faster, but for sure insecure (recommended RSA key sizes today >= 2048 bits).

Comment: @Topaco - There is always a trade-off, you just have to find that sweet spot. I suggest even trying AES for quicker decryption.

Comment: @NitishAnand - Before using a 512 bits key, I would rather try another library. Symmetric and asymmetric encryption cover different topics. Therefore, AES would only be a solution if the OP's requirements allow this (which of course may be, this is not clear from the question).

Comment: @Topaco I tried some other libs (react-native-rsa-native) but after spending so much time trying to resolve dependencies to work, I started experiencing run-time errors as for the latter, my superiors recommended asymmetric encryption but with this experience, I wanted to know why, or if its peculiar to just the Node-RSA ,

Comment: The performance of RSA decreases with the key size. So the larger the key, the worse the performance, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1569557) (but quite old). On the other hand, you can't choose an arbitrarily small key because the security decreases with the key size. Today, keys >= 2048 bits should be used.

Comment: Since you didn't post your key size, it's hard to compare. For a 2048 bits key, decryption with Node-RSA is typically in the low double-digit millisecond range for me, while key generation is in the single-digit second range, s. [here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/NewFragrantMemwatch). Your high decryption values seem to be more of a problem with your environment.

Comment: Thanks alot @Topaco, I went through the link you shared and got more insight into the cause of my challenge. Also my test device is a mobile device and I was able to access node crypto and other necessary dependencies using browserify for it to work.